# Given Points on Coordinate Axis , Find number of Right Triangles

Tags: geometry

A few points are given on X axis and a few on Y axis , Find number of right triangles using the given points as vertices.

Comment: I've seen some similar questions in the last week. Online contest?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is nice, just avoid extensive checking.

Put coordinates in (hash)map to provide almost O(1) access.

For every a^2 factorize it and check for divisors (and complementary ones) in the map.

(there is no more than 2*a divisors for a^2)

Comment: Thank you , I was wondering if there is a way to precompute the divisors of the first 10^5 squares?

Comment: What are limits for this task? I'm afraid that storage space for this table is too high. But approach is simple - like Eratosphene's sieve - for every K< Sqrt(10^5) just add it in K, 2K, 3K .... cells.

Comment: There would be a max of 10^5 points , and each coordinate can be upto 10^5 distance away from the origin . Takes too much time to calculate the divisors of first 10^5 squares by the O(√n) method , and the Modified sieve only works for numbers upto 10^7.